# error "application not installed on android device."

Tags: java, android, android-intent, permissions, apk

I have an application that works on the android emulator. After installing the application on my samsung galaxy 4 i tried to open it and i get an error saying application not installed.

My console shows some permission denial:

```
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000     cmp=com.example.autoconvert/.MainActivity} from null (pid=16425, uid=2000) requires android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.autoconvert"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/autoconvert"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.autoconvert.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: ordinary SDK applications cannot hold ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES.                  try removing this line from your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remvoe the following attribute from applicaton tag

```
    android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"
```

Comment: Please explain to me what this section of code does? So i know how to properly implement it when i need it.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know what is ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.autoconvert"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/autoconvert"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.autoconvert.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```